# is it possible to keep changes made with CSS transition?

Tags: jquery, css

When I do

```
#box {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #cc66ff;
}

#box:active {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
       -moz-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
        -ms-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
         -o-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
            transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
}
```

The changes discarded once I release the mouse button, is there  way to make them stay? to expand the box and keep it that way using CSS or/and JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$("#box").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({ width: "300px", height: "300px" }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 })
});
```

Or alternatively have your transition as a result of a css class, rather than the `:active` psuedoselector:

```
#box.active {
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
  -o-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
   transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
}

$("#box").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to animate it, as you are changing from one size to another, and your `:active` definition is only for that 'active' state.

I'm afraid you can't get away from using javascript on this one.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
 #box.expanded{
 width: 300px; height: 300px;
 }
```

jquery (js):

```
 $('#box').mouseup(function() { $(this).addClass('expanded'); });
```